# Firestore, Firebase Authentication, and Firestore Rules with multiple business entities

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to see if Firestore is the right tool for my need.

I am designing a multi-tenanted system using Firestore for scalability and security. Can this be done correctly using just Firestore, Firebase authentication, and Firebase rules to handle all CRUD operations? The idea behind the entities is:

```
System > Account > Business > Customer
```

Roles at each entity level would be:

```
Administrator, Manager, Support, Report, Unauthenticated (the customer)
```

Accounts have businesses and businesses have customers. Customers would not need to authenticate but read a specific document (designated by the business) and then create their own specific new document. They could create multiple documents but there would be time-based volume thresholds (no DOS!).

I believe Firestore Rules would work great if it didn’t have the Account as a superset that has multiple of the Businesses.

Is it possible to create a system like this with just Firestore, authentication, and rules alone? I want to keep things simple but also not pound a nail using a pair of pliers.

Thanks in advance for the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a set of well defined [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) you can indeed use Firestore for such a multi-tenant system.

In your security rules, you would combined the different claims, depending on the access role.

In particular you should:

1. Check the user has the correct claims e.g. `auth.token.businessId == "xyz"`, `auth.token.role == "Support"`
2. Check that the user is writing/reading a doc that corresponds to his entity, e.g. `allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId && request.resource.data.businessId == auth.token.businessId`

Don't forget that [Security Rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), so in each query executed by a user, you need to add the different ids from his/her custom claims (`businessId`, `accountId`, etc...). Either by mimicking your entities tree with (sub)collections, or by using some `where()` clauses in the queries.

---

Note that since Customers would not need to authenticate, they could potentially read and create documents from/for others businesses, if they have the ID of these businesses (i.e. the `DocumentReference`s).

---

You will probably have to manage a set of claims for each user (role, account, business, ... ), which can become complex, so you might be interested by the following article which explains how to [create an Admin module for managing Firebase users access and roles](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e).

Comment: If I understand, that would require having the business ID on each document as part of the authorizing process then? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, unless all the users with account authorization can read/write businesses in this account. It is difficult to answer precisely since we don't know how your security is applied to your tree structure. But as a rule of thumb, you should have in a given doc one ore more fields which correspond to the claim(s) of the user.

Comment: Thanks Renaud. The security around documents is definitely a mind-shift for me compared to a relational database. I appreciate the help.